# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent query by relationship column value

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Good day to you all...

I'm trying to access a collection based on a column in a related table within Eloquent (Laravel 4.2).

I have the following tables:

tags:

```
(int) id
(string) name
```

tag_usage:

```
(int) id
(string) model (the name of the model that is allowed to use the tag)
```

tag_tag_usage: (pivot)

```
(int) id
(int) tag_id
(int) tag_usage_id
```

I also have a taggables (polymorphic to store tags for multiple models) table which I believe is out of scope here as I only want to retrieve the tags that am allowed to use for each model.

My tag model has the relationship

```
public function usage()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('TagUsage');
}
```

and the TagUsage model has

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
}
```

Now, what I want to do is return the tags that ONLY have a specific usage, some pseudo code would be

get_tags->where(tag_usage.model = modelname)

which would return only a subset of the tags.

Tried a few things with no success so over to the many fine brains available here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `whereHas` in the following way:

```
$tags = Tag::whereHas('usage', function($q)
{
    $q->whereModel('modelname');

})->get();
```

Comment: Many thanks Marcin, exactly what I needed with the added bonus of gaining an understanding of the whereColumn method.

Comment: In addition I created a scope to add to the tag model...
`public function scopeByModel($query, $model)
    {

     return $query->whereHas('usage', function($q) use ($model)
  {
      $q->whereModel($model);
  });

    }`